# Download dynamic XML/JSON file in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to implement a feature where users can **download** their personal data in **XML or JSON format file**.

The file will be generated at run time and I have no idea how to implement this in Spring Boot in the corresponding `@RestController` of my application.

So far I've only implemented the creation of the appropriate XML or JSON String and at first I thought of sending it as a Response and let the front-end manage the rest but I don't think this is the way to go as a file download is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your file is created dynamically from a string, you will need to create an output stream and write the string content to it. I haven't tested any of this but I've used similar code in the past.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@RequestMapping("/downloadDocument")
public void downloadDocument(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest  request) throws IOException {
    //jsonPersonal is the string that you're going to create dynamically in your code
    final String jsonPersonal = " some json encoded data here";

    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setContentLength( jsonPersonal.length());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");

    //this copies the content of your string to the output stream
    IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.toInputStream(jsonPersonal), response.getOutputStream());
    

    response.flushBuffer();
}
```